# Is it possible to run both mongod and mongos at a time in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb,I would like to know is it possible to run both mongod and mongos instance at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you'll need to use different tcp ports as both mongod and mongos are using the same `27017` by default. You can specify ports using `--port <port>` flag as noted in [mongod](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--port) and [mongos](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongos/#cmdoption-mongos--port) docs.